# How to find MarkLogic v9 Data Hub version using linux command or something else

Tags: linux, marklogic

Is there a reliable way to query a MarkLogic v9.x system running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux v7.6 to determine the version of Data Hub that is running please?

I was hoping maybe a linux command might be possible, or maybe an API call?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DHF REST endpoint /v1/resources/mlHubversion will work in DHF 5.

DHF 5.4.0 will include a Gradle "hubVersion" task to simpify this.

Comment: Thanks. What command woukd i use for hub version 4.x ?

Comment: I found an alternative option : log onto the server directly via putty etc ,  go to /data/data-hub ( or whatever the data hub directory is ) . Then type "cat  gradle.properties". Then look for the line  "mlDHFVersion="  and you will see the data hub version as 4.x.x or 5.x.x.  Not sure if there is a programmatic way to  extract this ( e.g. XQuery or jscript) , if someone knows, it would be helpful

Comment: Same but it's ml:hubversion - see https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/refs/rest-extensions/

Comment: Do I need to create a new rest extension, or can I access an existing api with the Hubversion parameter and if so how would you do it? Thanks.

Comment: For DHF 4, just go to http://host:8010/v1/resources/ml:hubversion